# Initial requests sent over HTTP by default

Tags: tls, http, hsts

Before the invention of HSTS security policy, if a user didn't specify the protocol in the URL, were all the initial requests sent over HTTP by default for every website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst request is made over HTTP then the site redirects you to the HTTPS website.

Check out [this post](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2009/07/27/locking-up-the-valuables-opt-in-security-with-forcetls/)

It says it in an example of how sites used to work:

> More specifically, these are the steps for logging into the bank’s site:
>
> 1. You type “www.mybank.com” into the address bar and hit enter.
> 2. The browser assumes “www.mybank.com” should be requested over HTTP by default, so the initial request is unencrypted.
> 3. The server at “http://www.mybank.com” responds with an HTTP redirect to “https://www.mybank.com”
> 4. The secure connection is established, and a login page is served via HTTPS.
> 5. You enter your password and do your banking.

Comment: Is this only when HSTS is not implemented on websites?

Comment: This what they used to do before HSTS, if the website doesn't redirect you to HTTPS then you will remain on the HTTP website. I think HSTS has to be initiated by the browser and implemented in the browser as well